# Karma tests NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken fileName

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I know there are a few similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they don't quite answer my question.

When running Karma tests in my Angular project, I get this error:
`NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken app.config!`

I know that in my .spec file I need to specify a provider for InjectionToken, but I am not sure on exact syntax.

Here is my `app.config` file:

```
export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken("app.config");
export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {
  relativeDateLimit: 604800000,
  dateFormat: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
  ...
}
export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {
  relativeDateLimit: 604800000,
  dateFormat: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
  ...
}
```

Then in the .component.ts file I use it like so in the constructor:

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from '../../app.config';

constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) public appConfig) {}
```

Now in the .spec.ts file for this component I know that I need to set a provider for the `InjectionToken`

I tried doing it like so:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
...

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ RelativeDateComponent ],
      providers: [ InjectionToken ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

But this syntax does not work, because I also need to specify app.congig there somehow. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In *.spec.ts file need to add the following to providers array:

```
providers: [
  { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: AppConfig }
]
```

Comment: Isn't this concept should apply for the service injection also... For my case it is the mock class to use. As mentioned above, I am using { provide: Token.MyServiceInterface, useClass: MockMyServiceInterface }
It is throwing same error: "NullInjectorError: No provider for Injection Token Token.MyServiceInterface!"